# Migrating SharePoint workflow from one site to another site

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have finished creating my list workflows on my development machine. It also has custom InfoPath Forms attached to each of them.

Now I need to move it to Production. What will be my options?

I read that there is no way to move 'list workflows' however there is a few hacks to do it, i.e. through SharePoint designer. However seems that the InfoPath forms are not migrated.

Or is there any way to transform it quickly to a 'reusable workflow' so that I can export it too easily and quickly?

And what is the best way to migrate the InfoPath forms attached to each workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath forms can be created using REST CODE, Refer this article: http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/create-infopath-form-programmatically-using-rest-api-jsom-sharepoint-online/

You need to have template available.